# Android MapFragrement Missing Library libMAPSJNI.so

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to embed HereMap into my project. But I had encounter the following errors:

```
ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment,MISSING_LIBRARIES,Library /data/user/0/my_project_package/files/../lib/libMAPSJNI.so not found.,java.lang.Throwable
I:     at com.nokia.maps.at.a(EngineError.java:27)
I:     at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.b(MapsEngine.java:367)
I:     at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:343)
I:     at com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine.init(MapEngine.java:129)
I:     at com.nokia.maps.br.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:126)
I:     at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment.init(MapFragment.java:132)
```

Following are the codes to use HereMap:

```
gmMapFragment = new MapFragment();

activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(gmCenterView.getId(), gmMapFragment, "here_map_fragment").commit();

gmMapFragment.init(activity, new OnEngineInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
        if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
          gmMapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(gestureListener);
          // Exceptions are thrown here!!!

          gmMap = gmMapFragment.getMap();
          ....
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please share how you are including the HERE SDK in your build (e.g. your Gradle build files where HERE SDK is included). Have you made any `packagingOptions` declarations in Gradle?

Comment: Also, please ensure you are correctly adding the `MapFragment` programmatically. I cannot see where you are initializing `gmCenterView` from the code above, so unsure if it is correct. See this page for more info: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/dynamic-mapfragment.html

Answer (score 1):

I think I figure out what's wrong myself. It's that I didn't copy the "armeabi-v7a" folder with lots of .so files into the "jniLib" folder of my project. Sorry, I am pretty new on this.

Comment: Better to just migrate to our AAR instead of using this method. The AAR integration is much better

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response.

1. Following are my steps of adopting Here Map into my project:

   Step 1. Put the "HERE-sdk.jar" (also "HERE-sdk.jar.properties", "HERE-sdk-javadoc.jar") into the "lib" directory of my Android Studio project.

   Step 2. Add the following setup in the build.gradle:

   ```
   dependencies {
      ...        

      compile files('libs/HERE-sdk.jar')

      ...
   }
   ```
2. Yes that link was the instructions we followed when we started the Here Map coding. The "gmCenterView" is actually a "RelativeLayout" that we will put the map fragment on.

   ```
   public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {
       ...
   }

   MyView gmCenterView = ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to the latest SDK. We have switched our deployment methods with AAR files which bundle both the Jar and native libraries together.

What you have provided above will only include the jar library. You still need to add the native binaries to the gradle file for it to work.

Comment: Using the latest SDK is much easier. 

`dependencies {
    compile(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar')
}`